# ORA-06512: "value too large for column %s (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, join, oracle11g

ORA-06512: at line 23 12899. 00000 -  "value too large for column %s (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"
The above error is occuring while executing following query

```
    DECLARE  M_COUNT NUMBER;M_I18N_RESOURCEBASE_ID NUMBER;
    BEGIN FOR X IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(E.RESOURCE_ID,' ',''))) AS RESOURCE_ID, 
E.NAME_FR,
E.SHORT_DESC_FR,
E.DESCRIPTION_FR,
RBI.RESOURCE_ID AS RESOURCE_ID2 
FROM EXT_FRANCE_PRODUCT E 
JOIN RESOURCEBASEI18N RBI 
ON (TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(E.RESOURCE_ID,' ','')))=RBI.RESOURCE_ID) 
WHERE RBI.TYPE='producttype') 
LOOP SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO M_COUNT
        FROM I18N_RESOURCEBASE
        WHERE RESOURCE_ID=X.RESOURCE_ID
        AND LANGUAGE_ID  =41;
        IF M_COUNT       =0 THEN
        INSERT
          INTO I18N_RESOURCEBASE
            (
              LANGUAGE_ID,
              RESOURCE_ID,
              NAME,
              SHORT_DESCRIPTION,
              DESCRIPTION
            )
            VALUES
            (
              41,
              X.RESOURCE_ID,
              X.NAME_FR,
              X.SHORT_DESC_FR,
              X.DESCRIPTION_FR
            )
          RETURNING I18N_RESOURCEBASE_ID
          INTO M_I18N_RESOURCEBASE_ID;
          LOGGER.ERROR('Inserted trans are: Product '||M_I18N_RESOURCEBASE_ID);
        ELSIF M_COUNT=1 THEN
          UPDATE I18N_RESOURCEBASE
          SET NAME         =X.NAME_FR,
              SHORT_DESCRIPTION = X.SHORT_DESC_FR,
              DESCRIPTION = X.DESCRIPTION_FR
          WHERE RESOURCE_ID=X.RESOURCE_ID
          AND LANGUAGE_ID  =41;
          LOGGER.ERROR('Updated trans are: Product '||X.RESOURCE_ID);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

and I need to add exception in the above code so that I can add only those rows whose value is not too large for column.

Comment: Line 23 appears to be `NAME` in the INSERT statement. Check the table definition for this field and measure the size of the value being inserted (i.e. `X.NAME_FR`). Also note that, if you are using a different encoding than plain ASCII (e.g. UTFx), a character might take more than a single byte.

Comment: the size of name is 150 of insert statement and i cannot change that value so want to write an exception which skips the length>150 and add the value which is less than 150

Comment: include a LENGTH(e.name) in your cursor select and then test for it, or a SUBSTR(x.name) on the insert (if you would prefer to still insert a shortened NAME)

Comment: You can alternatively truncate the input in the insert like: `SUBSTR(X.NAME_FR,1,LENGTH(I18N_RESOURCEBASE.NAME#TYPE)...` (not sure about the syntax to get the length of the table column, so check it).